# Sub, divide and print rest of line with awk

Tags: awk

I am having some difficulty using awk to transform my source file. Specifically, I'd like to subtract each line from the top line, divide that number by 200, then print the rest of the line. Example input:

```
1000 : A0B0 add  %g1, %o1, %o2
2000 : A0B0 sub  %o1, %o2, %o2
3600 : A0B0 mov  %icc, 1, %o1
4000 : A0B0 add  %g4, %g4, %g4
```

Output:

```
0 : A0B0 add  %g1, %o1, %o2
5 : A0B0 sub  %o1, %o2, %o2
13 : A0B0 mov  %icc, 1, %o1
15 : A0B0 add  %g4, %g4, %g4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command, updated to truncate the numeric result (as per request via comment):

```
awk 'NR==1{top_line=$1} {$1=int(($1-top_line)/200); print $0}' data.txt
```

will yield:

```
0 : A0B0 add %g1, %o1, %o2
5 : A0B0 sub %o1, %o2, %o2
13 : A0B0 mov %icc, 1, %o1
15 : A0B0 add %g4, %g4, %g4
```

where `data.txt` contains:

```
1000 : A0B0 add  %g1, %o1, %o2
2000 : A0B0 sub  %o1, %o2, %o2
3600 : A0B0 mov  %icc, 1, %o1
4000 : A0B0 add  %g4, %g4, %g4
```

Comment: @TimmyThome I updated the answer to truncate the result, give it whirl and see if it works for you.